# Possible to use messages in enum?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am wondering if it's possible to have a enum with messages.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have nested messages, based on which enum is selected. The problem is easily solved by doing business logic checks using the optional identifier.

I am just looking for a more elegant business logic controll implementation than if-statement the hell out of the message to determine which code path to execute.

Something like this is what I have in mind. Is this possible to achieve?

```
message T {
    enum A {
        message T2 = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? Please add a language tag to your question. It would also be a good idea to provide some more context. Like give an example of how it normally works and then it will make more sense what you want to do. Very often, the right answer to questions on SO is not what you are actually asking for.

Comment: @FuzzyLogic well, the relevant language here would seem to be the DSL: proto2 / proto3...

Comment: I see, thanks @MarcGravell. I shoulda checked the tag description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - enumerations are simply named 32-bit integers; but there is `oneof` - I wonder if *that* is what you are looking for:

```
message T {
    oneof A {
        T2 t2 = 1;
        //...other options here
    }
}
message T2 {}
```